# Travis CI runs only on Pull Requests and in Expected for Branch

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have two builds at the same time when doing PR.
[image: Github Image]

According to docs, that could be turned off via [web interface](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/web-ui/#build-pushed-branches)
[image: web interface]

I turned that off (want to have only PR build) and also added `only` to `.travis.yml`, but still have two builds, but now branch builds just in expecting stage. In web UI Travis - no more builds for branch created.

[image]

```
branches:
  only:
  - master

language: python
os: linux
dist: xenial

jobs:
  include:
  - name: pytest
    python:
      - 3.7
    install:
      - pip install -U pip
      - pip install -U pytest
      - pip install -U PyYAML
      - pip install -U Cerberus
    script:
      - pytest -vvs
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this was the issue

https://travis-ci.community/t/known-issue-travis-ci-reports-expected-waiting-for-status-to-be-reported-on-the-github-status-api-but-the-status-never-arrives/1154

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your jobs using conditional checks like:

```
    - stage: build
      name: "build pull request"
      if: type IN (pull_request)
      install:
            echo 'Building pull request';
    ...
```

Each step inside this stage will only execute on PR builds.